# How to assign a variable in a column given another variable?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, variables, dataset, assign

This is my dataset :

[Datset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DOSo.png)

I want to assign to the different values* such as 'W M I HOLDINGS CORP' and 'MILESTONE SCIENTIFIC INC' another variable in the column 'ticker' in order to have the opportunity to sort them. 
In the column 'ticker' I need to add WMIH and WLSS respectively to the two different values.

How can I do that ?

I am going to expect the output with something like this :

[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPVJ6.png)

Comment: I am little confused. `W M I HOLDINGS CORP` and `MILESTONE SCIENTIFIC INC` aren't variables, but values in one column, right?
So you want to copy those values to the `ticker` column?

Comment: I need to add the values 'WMIH'  in correspondence of 'HOLDINGS CORP' and 'WLSS' in correspondence of 'MILESTONE SCIENTIFIC'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be ok with this. Assuming you have your dataset in `df` variable.

```
df.loc[df['comnam'] == 'W M I HOLDINGS CORP', 'ticker'] = 'WMIH'
df.loc[df['comnam'] == 'MILESTONE SCIENTIFIC INC', 'ticker'] = 'WLSS'
```